# Where do APK store setting information?

Tags: android, apk, adb

I am not a mainstream android developer but every now and then I have to deal with APK files and call their intent and activities using ADB.

Most of the times when I pull the file, it comes with config file and all the settings are stored there. If I want to change any settings, I am able to do it there.

However, recently pulled an Radio app and it has settings section and radio stations get stored BUT somehow, it does not have config file. That made me curious. how can I know where to read the settings of that file?

Comment: By "config file", did you mean `SharedPreference` file? (i.e. the file used to store user preference in app)

Comment: yes sir. That's corect!!